# Use the alternating series test to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^p}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We are supposed to either Abels formula, Dirichlet's test, or alternating series.I think if I let $a_k= \frac{1}{k^p}$ and show that it is decreasing I might be able to use the alternating series test but then I would also need to show that entire series is bounded as well.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $p$?

Comment: sorry p must be greater than $0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for any $p\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have that $\frac{1}{k^p} \geq \frac{1}{(k + 1)^p}$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k^p} = 0$. Thus by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}$ converges.

Comment: Okay so it looks like you used an approximation of L